# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите как справиться с ошибкой? я так понимаю что сервер не очень хочет отвечать на мои запросы и просто блокирует меня. Как это обойти?
Пытаюсь сохранять фото с сайта NASA. По идее все должно работать, т. к. это задание от курса Microsoft DEV330x и у всех работает. Но похоже НАСА задолбали запросами и они воткнули какую-то защиту от студентов.

```
%%writefile apod.py

import argparse
from datetime import date, timedelta
from random import randint
import os
import urllib.request

def parse_command_line():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d",'--date', nargs = 3, metavar = ("month", "day", "year"), action = "store", type = int, help = "month day year formatted date (i.e. 03 28 1998)")
    parser.add_argument ('-s', '--surprise', action = 'store_true', help = 'select a random date for a surprise image')
    parser.add_argument ('-k', '--api_key', action = "store", type = str, help = 'NASA developer key')
    parser.add_argument ('-v', '--verbose', action = 'store_true', help = 'verbose mode')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def create_date(datelist, surprise):

try:    
    if datelist != None:
        d = date(datelist[2], datelist[0], datelist[1])
        return d
    else:
        if surprise:
            start_date = date(1995,6,16)
            end_date = date.today()
            delta = end_date - start_date
            delta_random = randint(0, delta.days)
            d = date.today() - timedelta(delta_random)
            return d

        else: 
            end_date = date.today()
            d = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1) 
            return d

except :
    return None

def query_url(d, api_key):
    global date_obj
date_obj = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
URL = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key={}&date={}"
complete_URL = URL.format(api_key,date_obj)
return complete_URL


def save_image(d, image):


year = d.strftime("%Y")
month = d.strftime("%m")
file_path = year+"/"+month+"/"+date_obj+".jpg"
open(file_path, 'wb')
return file_path



def request(url):


# request the content of url and save the retrieved binary data
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read()

# convert data from byte to string
data = data.decode('UTF-8')

# convert data from string to dictionary
data = eval(data)
return data

def download_image(url):

# request the content of url and return the retrieved binary image data
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    image = response.read()
return image

def main():
# NASA developer key (You can hardcode yours for higher request rate limits!)
API_KEY = "cZX0zRDveiz7AfGfOW23typMH3NCnS3uvQJc0ZNS"

# parse command line arguments
args = parse_command_line()

# update API_KEY if passed on the command line
print(args.api_key)
if args.api_key != '':
    API_KEY = args.api_key

# create a request date
d = create_date(args.date, args.surprise)

# ascertain a valid date was created, otherwise exit program
if d is None:
    print("No valid date selected!")
    exit()

# verbose mode
if args.verbose:
    print("Image date: {}".format(d.strftime("%b %d, %Y")))

# generate query url
url = query_url(d, API_KEY)

# verbose mode    
if args.verbose:
    print("Query URL: {}".format(url))

# download the image metadata as a Python dictionary
metadata = request(url)

# verbose mode    
if args.verbose:
    # display image title, other metadata can be shown here
    print("Image title: {}".format(metadata['title']))

# get the url of the image data from the dictionary
image_url = metadata['url']

# verbose mode    
if args.verbose:
    print("Downloading image from:", image_url)

# download the image itself (the returned info is binary)
image = download_image(image_url)

# save the downloaded image into disk in (year/month)
# the year and month directories correspond to the date of the image (d)
# the file name is the date (d) + '.jpg'
save_image(d, image)

print("Image saved")

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Статус ошибки 403 означает, что Вы авторизованы но не имеете прав для доступа ресурса.

Comment: и что в таком случае делать? это мой первый опыт парсинга, я ненастоящий сварщик

Comment: @AntonZubochenko ну как минимум нужно авторизоваться на ресурсе, также может быть что в .htaccess прописаны ip адреса с которых РАЗРЕШЕН доступ к ресурсу, а остальные заблокированы что маловероятно.

Comment: @tramway но там нет никакой авторизации. этот api_key в открытом доступе был взят.

Comment: Попробуйте указать User-Agent реального браузера в подключении. Возможно запрет по нему стоит на стороне целевого сайта. Такое используют для снижения нагрузки на ресурсы.

Comment: @Rootware можете помочь конкретикой, как это сделать?

Comment: @AntonZubochenko Не надо ничего этого делать. Если у вас есть API_KEY в коде, то все хорошо, я проверил - все работает с вашим ключом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подправьте вот этот кусок кода и все:

```
# update API_KEY if passed on the command line
print(args.api_key)
if args.api_key:
    API_KEY = args.api_key
```

Вы просто не правильно проверку делали, поэтому в complete_url вы получали None вместо ключа.

Comment: спасибо, похоже ошибка и правда была тут. и это, кстати, странно, потому что эту часть кода писал не я, а она была в задаче. теперь правда пишет что нет файла в директории когда я пытаюсь его записать с помощью open(file_path, 'wb'). сейчас буду дальше ковырять код.

Comment: @AntonZubochenko Нет файла, потому что вы просто не создали папку, куда хотите сохранить файл. Чтобы создать полный путь сразу можно использовать: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs а чтобы проверить, что папка существует, можно: `s.path.exists("/path/path/path")`

Comment: сделал чуть чуть иначе:     if os.path.isdir(folder) != True:
        os.makedirs(folder)

    file_path = folder + date_obj+".jpg"
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image)